# Sparse denormalised relations using Cassandra - CQL3/2/1 or thrift?

Tags: cassandra

*or...*

**How to log our audit-trail using cassandra?**

I have the following relational model that I am using as the basis for an experiment to see if we can use Cassandra to store the many-hundred million queryable rows.

```
| datetime | planet | continent | country | state | <...> | street | who_id | who_name | msg | p1 | p2 | p3 |
```

Any one of these entities may generate an audit log entry. Moreover, a low-down entry will have all the references of it's ancestry stored alongside it; so lookups based on high-level entities will return everything that happened below it.[1]  Using PostgreSQL, we will have largely empty dense rows: One benefit of Cassandra is sparse rows. (No street column NULL for a continent-based log entry).  There are at present 25 entities which have relations in various permutations.

We also want to retain the names of the entities in the object graph, at the time the event happened.

I thought I had got to grips with the datamodel and thought that I would model it like this.

*Using arbitrary composite columns for the relational links.*

```
| (row key)        | planet:1 | continent:101 | country:44 | who:4 | msg             | p1 | p2 | p3   |  
| COUNTRY:TimeUUID | ---------+---------------+------------+-------+-----------------+----+----+------| 
|                  |  "earth" | "europe"      | " UK"      | "Rob" | "*it happnzd!!" | 1  | 5  | true |
```

My aim was to be able to search for who:4 and get all of their changes out.
likewise, grabbing the rows that have planet:1 - shows all changes that happened on earth.

The entity-link columns are dynamic (or at least that's what I thought) They will be used in weird and wonderful combinations. And it thought it was a boon not having to specify them up front, and by using composite typed column names, would be queryable.

- A. I'm still not sure if this is do-able in any flavour of cassandra.
- B. I can't work out how to get this situation in CQL3. Any help there would be appreciated.
- C. Should I use/care about CQL?(3)? is CQL3 the future or is thrift/pelops still a futureproof way to go?

12months ago - I read about Cassandra and bought a couple of books on the subject. By the time I read them and started a project that may benefit, the world has changed and stuff I grappled with mentally is abandoned in favour of something which looks like SQL. so now i'm just as confused.

[1] denormalising here makes sense for in fact the audit log is a historical snapshot, so it records the exact object graph "*at the time the event occurred*"

Answer (score 0):

I believe that nulls are free in Cassandra.  That is, if a column in a row is NULL, that is *not* stored by recording some kind of "null flag". Instead, nothing at all is stored for that column. So a denormalised schema that has many columns that are mostly null is not expensive.